# Display Models with Foreign Keys and Pagination

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I have a flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2 app with the follwing problem.
I am trying to display a model in an html table and have pagination with it.  The model has a bunch of foreign keys in it, so in the table I see the foreign key.  I would like to display the `__repr__` of the model or one of the fields of that model.
`# models.py`

```
class WorkLog(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'work_log'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mechanic = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    building_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('buildings.id'))
    elevator_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('elevators.id'))
    work_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('work_type.id'))
    component_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('component.id'))
    date = db.Column(db.Date(), default=datetime.utcnow().date())
    time_in = Column(TIME(), default=(datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=4)).time())
    time_out = Column(TIME(), default=(datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=2)).time())
    notes = db.Column(db.Text)
```

The view function passes model with pagination

`#views.py`

```
# build the time review table with pagination
    u = User.query.get(current_user.get_id())

    work_logs = u.work_log.paginate(page, 10, False).items

    return render_template('mechanic/mechanic.html', form=form, logs=work_logs)
```

The relevant part of the template

mechanic.html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Building</th>
                            <th>Elevator</th>
                            <th>Work Type</th>
                            <th>Time In</th>
                            <th>Time Out</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for log in logs %}

                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ log.building_id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ log.elevator_id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ log.work_type_id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ log.time_in }}</td>
                                <td>{{ log.time_out }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

It is the three fields ending id that are a foreign key and that would like to display the `__repr__` for that object or a field.  What is my best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an alias function to your model class to get the foreign key attribute.

```py
class WorkLog(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'work_log'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mechanic = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    building_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('buildings.id'))
    elevator_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('elevators.id'))

    # ...

    @property
    def building(self):
        return Buildings.query.filter_by(id=self.bulding_id).first()

    @property
    def elevator(self):
        return Elevators.query.filter_by(id=self.elevator_id).first()

    # Repeat the same for other
    # ...
```

In your HTML, all you have to do is call the function after the class instance.

```html
  <tbody>
     {% for log in logs %}
      <tr>
         <td>{{ log.building }}</td>
         <td>{{ log.elevator }}</td>
         <!--- ... -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the relationship between the two models— you've already defined the `FK` relationship, so something simple like:

```
buildings = db.relationship('Buildings')
```

would enable you to do `{{ log.buildings }}` to get the `__repr__` of the `Buildings` object.

Comment: Thanks!  I had already had the relationship there in the other models using `relationship()` with the `backref=` option.  So I was able to use `log.building` in the template and it worked.